# How can I add a product to an existing and paid Woocommerce order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce website where one of my customers bought a product and a cable.

This customers bought a cable that isn't compatible with the other product, and asked if we could ship him the compatible one, that has the same price.

Maybe it's a stupid question, but how can I edit the order, which has been already paid, removing the incompatible cable and adding the correct product?

Is it possibile? Do I need a plugin or something?

Thank you in advance,
Luca

Answer (score 7):

If the status of the order is not "On Hold" (e.g., `completed`), then editing is not possible by default.

To allow editing for all order statuses, you can use the `wc_order_is_editable` filter:

```
add_filter( 'wc_order_is_editable', '__return_true' );
```

(you can put this code in the `functions.php` file of your theme, for example)

Answer (score 3):

**If and when** an order is "On Hold" , when you go to that order , you will see a button under Order Items called "Add line item(s)"
CLick on that and it will then be called "Add product(s)"
Click again and add the desired product by your customer.
After you add that product you can delete the one your customer doesn't want.

You also have the option to add a small extra fee (if you like) for doing that for them or not, up to you . Or update shipping etc.

Please note that in order for this to work, the order status must be "On Hold".

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit the order, change status to "pending payment" status, click "Update".
2. To delete an item, look for the small x icon, with a tooltip "delete item".
3. To add an item, click "Add Item".
4. Click Update.
5. Change the status back to "completed", click "Update".