# WooCommerce - Change customer order after it has been placed and paid

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Using three plugins:
WooCommerce
Subscriptio
WooEvents

I have created a product which allows for a customer to pay for an event over five instalments.

A customer has placed an order and made their first of the five payments via PayPal and has then contacted me to advise they have booked the wrong event.

The correct event is exactly the same except the dates are a month sooner.

I have added the following snippet to be able to edit 'processing' orders:

```
add_filter( 'wc_order_is_editable', 'wc_make_processing_orders_editable', 10, 2 );
function wc_make_processing_orders_editable( $is_editable, $order ) {
    if ( $order->get_status() == 'processing' ) {
        $is_editable = true;
    }

    return $is_editable;
}
```

From the order screen within the back-end of WordPress I can see that the the order can be edit by way of removing the product from the order or editing the meta data and cost.

The correct product that should have been ordered has a different product/variation ID.

My question is simply:

Should I remove the incorrectly ordered product from the order and add the correct product (both have the same properties with the exception of the courses dates); or
Should I just change the meta data and increase the stock levels for the incorrectly product back to X and reduce the stock level for the correct product?

Answer (score 0):

Your second option is much better. Change the meta from database if its accessible and then manage the stock accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet done this, but according to this exchange ...

[How can I add a product to an existing and paid Woocommerce order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275457/how-can-i-add-a-product-to-an-existing-and-paid-woocommerce-order)

... you can set the order status to "On Hold" and make changes to the order itself.  I presume you would then return the status to "Processing".

I would expect that if the application permits those changes, then it would be doing the background meta changes to inventory levels, etc., and spare you the problem of doing so (and the potential errors that may occur when messing with the data tables outside of the application).

Like I said, I haven't done this.  But it might be worthwhile doing a little test to make sure it works as it seems to be described in the answer to the other question.

J